# Firebase Analytics custom event average value

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, average, firebase-analytics

How can I set up FB Analytics in a way that it calculates the average value of a specific custom event? I'm using it on Android. This is the code of the custom event log:

```
public void logLevel(int level){
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putInt("user_level", level);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("user_level", params);
}
```

If the app sends level 10 from one device and level 20 from another one I want firebase to display avg level 15. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that way you're logging the event and its parameter is correct. Once your event is visible in the Event page of Firebase console, add the parameter in [reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en). Make sure to select the right data type, which is Number for your case.

Keep logging the data and you should be able to see similar to this:

[image]

This is the **score** parameter of **post_score** event in the [Firebase demo project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7157552?hl=en). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I had to add a parameter to it.

Comment: Nice tip @looptheloop88, would it be possible to further filter this to know the breakdown by device type or do I need to add more sophistication to data being sent as parameters ?